# An NSButton with two combined images (Cocoa OSX)

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsbutton

I want to make a type of popupbutton sort of like the action button on OSX.  I need to make the button have two images makeup the representation of the button (the icon for the button and the downward facing disclosure triangle next to it).  I was thinking maybe I could add the second image as a subview of the button but it seems that there should be a simpler way to do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: What do you need to do differently to the standard action button?

Comment: I want all the buttons that have pull down menus to have the disclosure down arrow.  Not all of these buttons will have the action button graphic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an NSPopUpButton whose `pullsDown` is set to `YES` (Type of “Pull Down” in IB) and whose image is set to the image named `NSImageNameActionTemplate` (“NSActionTemplate” in IB).

Comment: That would just give me a button with the action button logo.  I need to be able to combine and image with the disclosure down arrow.  So for example if the image of my button was a + then I want want to have the button show up as a + followed by the image of the disclosure down arrow.

Comment: Michael Minerva: Read my answer more thoroughly. A *pop-up* button, *whose `pullsDown` is set to `YES`*, will do exactly what you want.